# Throwing a CalloutException for Aura Controller

Tags: apex, aura, exception

I have an aura controller which calls a Services class. This services class makes a callout to external system and returns a response.

```
public class Anauracontroller{
  public resObj callService(){
    try{
      ServicesToCall.makeCall();
    }Catch(AuraException ex){

    }
  } 
}
```

Service class:

```
public class ServicesToCall{

 public static resObj makeCall(){

 }

}
```

Please pardon any coding standards that I might have violated here.

My question: Can an auraException handle all sort of exception- Example if there is any CalloutException? Does it make sense to create a customException here?

Answer (score 3):

You can catch any kind of catchable exception (not, for example, `LimitException`) and re-raise it as an `AuraHandledException` to handle it cleanly in your client-side JavaScript controller.

```
try {
    ServicesToCall.makeCall();
} catch (CalloutException ex) {
    throw new AuraHandledException(ex.getMessage());
}
```

Creating the exception by passing a string to its constructor ensures that you get a 'nice' display in Lightning with a user-friendly message (well, as user-friendly as the underlying exception's message, here), and not a long and technical stack trace.

Comment: Thanks. I was wondering if it is a exception due to callout - like if the service was not available. How would that be displayed in auraHandler exception's getMessage() method?

Comment: The error message that your JavaScript controller will access on the response object will be whatever you pass to `AuraHandledException`'s constructor. You can decide whether you want that to be the underlying exception's message or a custom string.

Comment: @SfdcBat To add pointer on what **DavidReed** was saying read [Basic Error Handling](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2017/09/error-handling-best-practices-lightning-apex.html)